# How to play audio in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Open html in whatsapp but audio can't running in background

```
<audio id="my_audio" loop>
            <source src='https://codepediacamp.000webhostapp.com/mp3/you-raise-me-up-josh-groban.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'>
            <source src='https://codepediacamp.000webhostapp.com/mp3/you-raise-me-up-josh-groban.ogg' type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("my_audio").play();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the same code, my firefox browser stopped auto play immediately, but once allowing for auto play and reloading the page, the song started playing. But my chrome stopped autoplay, to allow for autoplay in chrome please refer
[this article](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/)

Comment: i ran the code with brackets, song is started playing at google chrome, at i send hmtl in whatsapp and opened song not playing. Problem resolved make button for playing that hihihii